# CMAKE - runtime library hidden files

Tags: cmake, anaconda

I am running Linux Redhat, I have Anaconda installed and I am trying to install a program (libspimage) using `CMAKE` amd I get the following warning/error:

> CMake Warning at src/CMakeLists.txt:74 (ADD_LIBRARY):
>      Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target _spimage_pybackend
>      because files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
>      directories:
>   runtime library [libtiff.so.5] in /usr/lib64 may be hidden by files in:
>   /home/michantia/anaconda2/lib

Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.

When I do:

> echo $PATH

I get:

> /home/mi_a/anaconda2/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/michantia/.local/bin:/home/michantia/bin

I tried:

> export PATH=/usr/lib64:$PATH

hoping cmake would find the libraries in this directory before finding them in anancoda's, but that did not work. I also tried two other similar suggestions for a similar problem that I saw in stackoverflow, but that did not work.

Any other ideas are highly welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Warning message

> Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target

is related **neither** with *CMake* ability to find a library (`libtiff.so.5` in your case) **nor** with a *linker* ability to link the library.

The warning message means that when a target (`_spimage_pybackend`) will be loaded, the **loader will be unable to choose the correct library**: according to the [loader's algorithm](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) and the target's setting, file `/home/michantia/anaconda2/lib/libtiff.so.5` will be choosen instead of proper one `/usr/lib64/libtiff.so.5`.

The error is usually resulted in linking into the single target two libraries from *different* directories, when the directory with a second library also contains a file with the name of the first library:

1. Directory `/usr/lib64` contains a library `libtiff.so.5`, which is linked into the target.
2. Directory `/home/michantia/anaconda2/lib` contains a library `<A>` which is also linked into the target; but this directory also contains a file `libtiff.so.5`.

According to [CMake algorithm](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling), runpath for the binary file of such target will include both directories, so both libraries could be found. But such runpath confuses the loader to find the first library properly.

Except from avoiding such situation (when a library is contained in two directories), one hardly is able to handle this warning.

Comment: How can this be rectified?